# Changing working directory in Xcode for all users

Tags: xcode, configuration

It seems that Xcode stores an application's custom working directory in per-user settings. If I change the directory in **Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Options** it is saved into a file called `xcuserdata/myUserName.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/Program.xcscheme`

How do I change it for all users, not just myself? I want to distribute an Xcode project with a custom running directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution: There is a checkbox called "**shared**" in the scheme management dialog. Somehow I missed it.